C++ Registry Pattern
I have a large project, using CMake.
Suppose we have the following: Interface.hh, Registry.hh && .cc
I'd like to have the following design:
Implementation implements Interface.
Registry has a map from String to Interface.
Implementation ONLY includes "Registry.hh" and is referenced nowhere else in the system.
Implementation must insert itself into the Registry map.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to implement this in this very very simple system I have described without a lot of complexity or overhead.
I've looked into static. My problem is that it invokes undefined behavior, especially if I have a static Registry object and use static initializers to have them insert themselves. There is no guarantee these run, since no code in the translation unit would ever be called from elsewhere without these running.

It is implementation-defined whether or not the dynamic initialization (dcl.init, class.static, class.ctor, class.expl.init) of an object of namespace scope is done before the first statement of main. If the initialization is deferred to some point in time after the first statement of main, it shall occur before the first use of any function or object defined in the same translation unit as the object to be initialized.

I've also looked into __attribute__((constructor)). This seems potentially fruitful, especially if I specify the order so that the Registry map is constructed before any insertions occur. I'm not entirely certain the order-specification works across translation units.
Something I'm uncertain about is what the linking will look like in the CMakeLists for something like this.
The question:

How can something like this be done in C++ so that these Implementations register themselves to the Registry prior to main running (or, more flexibly, prior to the map's usage) without invoking undefined behavior, in the simplest possible manner?

As described, the implementation headers must not be included anywhere else in the system. They must self-register.


What link dependencies are necessary to make this work and make sure the registrations run and are successful?

I'd prefer the implementation to be as simple as possible, ideally making use of the least amount of unnecessary boilerplate and other code possible. The Registry does not need to be generic, and the Interface is static.

"it invokes undefined behavior ... no guarantee these run" Your quote doesn't say "undefined behavior", it says "implementation-defined [whether it works or not]", it's a different thing. We've been doing exactly this, and didn't have any issues. The only tricky part is that the registry itself must be a function-local static, to avoid static init order fiasco.

@HolyBlackCat The sentence that concerns me is "it shall occur before the first use of any function or object defined in the same translation unit as the object to be initialized". There is no guarantee that any function or object in that translation unit is used, if this insertion does not occur. I'd prefer to rely on the C++ standard in order to get an implementation-independent guarantee of the insertion.

There is no way to achieve what you want relying only on the C++ standard. __attribute__((constructor)) isn't part of the standard, but if you can use it, you don't need to, because a simple namespace scope object initialization will work just fine (this feature and __attribute__((constructor)) are implemented exactly the same way). Make the map function-static and you will not have any order problems.

@n.m.couldbeanAI Are you suggesting to use __attribute__((constructor)) in conjunction with, essentially, Meyer's singleton? The impression I am receiving is yes, if I am reading the standard correctly, where if I use globals for the insertion, there is no the insertions would be done. Additionally, do you know what I would need to do for linking? I'm thinking to simply link the implementations against the final binary in my CMake.

I do not suggest using __attribute__((constructor)). Static initialization will do the exact same thing in all implementations that have __attribute__((constructor)), and in implementations that don't have it, you cannot use it. So there is no point. You are not reading the standard correctly. First, there is no __attribute__((constructor)) in the standard so you can't read anything about it there. Second, the standard does not say that there will be no insertions, it says it's implementation defined. I do suggest having the registry itself as Meyer's singleton.

@n.m.couldbeanAI the standard states "[static initialization] shall occur before the first use of any function or object defined in the same translation unit as the object to be initialized". My interpretation is that static initialization could potentially NOT occur if no object or function from that TU is used. Is this correct? Given this implementation, no object from that TU will ever be able to be used unless the insertion occurs in the first place, which means that there is no guarantee that the insertion occurs at all.

You're vastly overthinking it. The standard isn't the ultimate source of truth. In some areas, it essentially describes the existing implementations rather than prescribing what they should do (e.g. most things regarding object lifetimes, aliasing, and then this). It works in all implementations I know of. It's not like a compiler/linker update could break it, people depend on this behavior.

The standard says this: "it is implementation defined whether or not the dynamic initialization is done before the first statement of main". In every implementation known to me that has __attribute__((constructor)), it is done before the first statement of main, and the behaviour is documented (these two things are implemented identically because there is no reason not to). So there is no point in using __attribute__((constructor)) (unless your code is in C). In an implementation that does not have __attribute__((constructor)) or anything similar, you are on your own.

I see. Thanks for the clarification @n.m.couldbeanAI . I've just always learned to try to strive to avoid implementation-defined behavior. I'm trying to look into constexpr and see, perhaps there might be a meta-template approach to this, since all the info should be known at compile-time.

It's impossible to do with constexpr at compile-time, because the full list is only known at link-time. Any constexpr implementation would only work inside individual TUs, and not across TUs.

I do this a lot, except that I don't use useless propietary compiler stuff like __attribute__((constructor)). Instead, I usually have some static Modules::Init<MyModule> init; , with Init<> usually just building a list of these. It doesn't create any modules at this stage, because we're before main() and these things usually connect to some machinery anyway. Later, when something needs the modules, it can just walk through the list and create them as needed.
